# Hibernate: получить только часть колонок таблицы.

Tags: hibernate, java

День добрый, господа!

Есть таблица с большим количеством колонок. На эту таблицу аннотациями замаплена некая сущность. Этот маппинг очень не хотелось бы менять.
Задача: надо получить из таблицы данные, которые касаются лишь малой части колонок. Как это лучше сделать?

Я вижу такие варианты:

1) Замапить на таблицу новую сущность.

2) Загрузить ненужные свойства как lazy. Не совсем понимаю как это сделать, не меняя основного маппинга. И кроме того, насколько я понимаю, в таком случае в ДАО мне придется использовать Session, а вспомогательные классы более высокого уровня типа EntityManager и ли спринговые HibernateTemplate пролетают т.к. они закрывают сессию после загрузки.

3) Использовать criteria.multiselect, который вернет массив нужных мне полей моей сущности. Я нашел такой пример в Hibernate Reference:

```
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteria = builder.createQuery( Object[].class );
Root<Person> personRoot = criteria.from( Person.class );
Path<Long> idPath = personRoot.get( Person_.id );
Path<Integer> agePath = personRoot.get( Person_.age );
criteria.multiselect( idPath, agePath );
criteria.where( builder.equal( personRoot.get( Person_.eyeColor ), "brown" ) );
List<Object[]> valueArray = em.createQuery( criteria ).getResultList();
for ( Object[] values : valueArray ) {
    final Long id = (Long) values[0];
    final Integer age = (Integer) values[1];
    ...
}
```

(Примерно то же можно сделать через Tuple. Нужно ли? Что дает использование Tuple?)

В приведенном коде не пойму одну вещь: что такое здесь Person_ ? Это же не сама сущность Person, а что тогда?

Ну а глобально - какой способ лучше?

Comment: Я бы добавил новую сущность.

Comment: Как вариант, написать запрос на HQL, который выберет только нужные поля.

Comment: Новая сущность это ок. Правда если надо получить только одно поле то выглядит не очень. Ну а HQL запрос это примерно то же что и на Criteria, если я правильно понял.